# Como usar archivo json para que cada diccionario dentro de el me determine como se vera una plantilla html con django

Tags: python, json, django

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de django en el curso de Python de Jetbrains Academy y mi objetivo en la etapa en la que estoy es utilizar la informacion de este archivo json:

```
[{"created": "2020-02-09 14:15:10", "text": "Text of the news 1", "title": "News 1", "link": 1}, {"created": "2020-02-10 14:15:10", "text": "Text of the news 2", "title": "News 2", "link": 2}, {"created": "2020-02-09 16:15:10", "text": "Text of the news 3", "title": "News 3", "link": 3}]
```

para que cada diccionario llene el contenido de una plantilla html, esto es lo que estoy intentando hacer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> {{ thenews.title }} </h2>
<p>{{ thenews.created }}</p>
<p>{{ thenews.text }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi news/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.views import View

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Coming soon")

with open(r"C:\Users\ed\PycharmProjects\HyperNews Portal\HyperNews Portal\task\news.json", "r") as json_file:
    news_from_json = json.load(json_file)

class News(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return render(request, r'C:\Users\ed\PycharmProjects\HyperNews Portal\HyperNews Portal\task\hypernews\news\templates\news\news.html', context = {'thenews':news_from_json} )
```

Este es mi news/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = "home"),
    re_path('news/(?P<link>[^/]*)/?', views.News.as_view()),
]
```

Y este es mi hypernews/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('news.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Si voy a http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/1 por ejemplo lo que obtengo es una pagina en blanco y lo mismo con news/ seguido de cualquie indice:
[image: Imagen de como se ve la pagina]

Si inspecciono el elemento de la pagina sale esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link id="avast_os_ext_custom_font" href="chrome-extension://mbckjcfnjmoiinpgddefodcighgikkgn/common/ui/fonts/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la variable de contexto `thenews` como tal, **es una lista**, que tiene diccionarios como items, por eso no se muestra nada. De hecho muestras el contenido del archivo JSON y se puede ver claramente que es una lista.

Tienes que iterar la lista y mostrar los datos:

```
{% for dic in thenews %}
   <h2> {{ dic.title }} </h2>
   <p>{{ dic.created }}</p>
   <p>{{ dic.text }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.